# How to connect Grails 3.0 to my local Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, grails, grails-3.0

I'm quite new with Grails and trying to connect my application to my local mysql database. Since I'm working with the latest version of Grails, I couldn't really find a lot of documentation to help me out. Is there any clear documentation which could guide me in the right direction?

(I've tried the official documentation, but it seems to be out of date)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Datasource configuration in Grails 3 now is done also via the `grails-app/conf/application.yml` file.  In a default project it is located in the final section of the file (starting with `dataSource:`).  The [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments) as of 2015-08-01 still explain the old, v2, syntax.  But for the developer this should be seen just as a change in syntax (from a Groovy DSL to a YAML).  E.g.:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: sa
    password:

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://liveip.com/liveDb
```

Add the mysql deps as `runtime` in the `dependencies` of your `build.gradle`.  E.g.

```
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
```

Comment: I figured it out. This is indeed how it works, thanks :)

Comment: How does one configure properties using this new syntax?

Comment: That´s what I left `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'`

Comment: Not working for me, I think it´s the environment url

Answer (score 0):

url: jdbc:mysql:///product
this link is working if we are working with the localhost

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).