# Cannot connect mysql to Grails 3 application

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-3.1

I am using grails version 3.1.4 and I am trying to connect my application to mysql database.
I had followed the link at [How to connect Grails 3.0 to my local Mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764922/how-to-connect-grails-3-0-to-my-local-mysql-database) to connect mysql database to my Grails 3 application but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceInterceptor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.grails.orm.hibernate4.support.AggregatePersistenceContextInterceptor.setHibernateDatastores(org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore] found for dependency [array of org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at helloworld.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.grails.orm.hibernate4.support.AggregatePersistenceContextInterceptor.setHibernateDatastores(org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore] found for dependency [array of org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore] found for dependency [array of org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this release.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error |
Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this release.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my application.yml

```
dataSource:
      pooled: true
      jmxExport: true
      driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      username: root
      password: root123


environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/collegedb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true
```

I have also added `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'` to build.gradle file.

I have created the database named collegedb at mysql. Can't figure out what is the problem. Any help/suggestions are appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Tried bumping up to 3.1.5 to see if the bug is fixed there?

Comment: @christopher: Ok. Thanks. Any other suggestions ??

Comment: And the proverbial `grails clean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misstyped config in application.yml:

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/collegedb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true
```

It should be:

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/collegedb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: Weglarz: Where is the mis-typing ?

Comment: @Nikhil: YAML files are indentation sensitive - you have indentation missing for your dbCreate and url. Indentation means that given package is a subpackage for the one preceding.

Comment: Weglarz: Worked like a charm. Cheers !!. Maybe you can please write the same in the answer section (edit) your post and I'll  mark your answer as correct anyways. Thanks.